# Ambiguous summation/sigma notation $ \sum_{k=⟨N⟩} a_k $

Tags: summation, notation

While studying Fourier transforms, I came across an ambiguous summation notation : $ k = ⟨N⟩ $ . It appears in [this](https://mlichouri.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/fundamentals-of-signals-and-systems.pdf) book.

What does the $' k = ⟨N⟩ '$ under the following summation/sigma notation mean for the terms that are being summed in this summation?

$$ \sum_{k=⟨N⟩} a_k  $$

The ambiguous notation (under the sigma) is the following: $$ k = ⟨N⟩ $$

It has the variable of the index of the summation term on the left of the equal  sign and left/right angle brackets around the 'N' variable on the right of the equal sign.

$$ $$

'k' takes values depending on 'N' but how? What is the meaning of the notation for the '$a_k$' terms that are being summed?
Does it mean we sum the terms ''from the first to the 'N-th' '' term or 'from the 0-th to '(N-1)-th' '' term? Or something else?

Edit:
More specifically, it appears in the pdf pages [658,660](https://mlichouri.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/fundamentals-of-signals-and-systems.pdf) in appendix D - transforms table rows of the online book.

Comment: What does $⟨N⟩$ represent?

Comment: Please provide some context. Where have you found this formula?

Comment: Maybe $k=⟨N⟩$ should read like $k\in\mathbb N$ ? But that would require the sequence to be absolutely convergent, as for example, when all the $a_k>0$.

Comment: @vitamind this is the question I am posting. It represents the values of k to do the summation over $a_k$ terms.

Comment: @GyroGearloose this is a question about the meaning of the summation notation $  = ⟨⟩ $ I don't think it has to do with the convergence or divergence of the series.

Comment: @md2perpe this formula is in a university textbook about signals.

Comment: "this formula is in a university textbook about signals", so please include it to your question. $<anything>$ could mean *anything*, misleading those who want to answer. Maybe, you even find a definition in your textbook.

Comment: @GyroGearloose it is not <anything> , it is a constant number in brackets, <N>. You can also find it in this online textbook for your ease: https://mlichouri.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/fundamentals-of-signals-and-systems.pdf , in page 662.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see it, neither on what the pdf-viewer shows as page 662, nor what in the pdf has as page numbered 662. Maybe you can explain about it?

Comment: @GyroGearloose the notation appears on many parts on appendix D (transforms table) of the online pdf I posted before. I will use the book pages written on the pdf. page 658 first table entry. Page 660 first and 9th table entry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This notation is used in the Discrete-Time Fourier tables in pages [658-660](https://mlichouri.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/fundamentals-of-signals-and-systems.pdf). The definition is
$$⟨N⟩:=\{0,1,2,...,N-1\}\Longrightarrow\sum_{k=⟨N⟩}=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}.$$
This is unconventional notation and in my opinion makes things more confusing than they have to be.

I was able to find the meaning by comparing the results in the tables with results I know, for instance, Parseval Equality (here the discrete case) on page 660 is normally written like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem#Notation_used_in_engineering) and also on page 660 the definition of the Discrete-Time Fourier Transform is usually written like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition).